# bash "for loop"

Tags: bash, scripting

When I do,

```
for ((i=0; i<"${ARRAY}"; i+=2))
do
    echo $i
    echo ${ARRAY[$i]}
done
```

`echo $i` works as I expected, also `echo ${ARRAY[0]}` works, but with `$i` as iterator `i` see only blank lines. How to write the for loop correctly?

Comment: 'loop-device' is not related to a 'for loop'. Please consider removing the 'loop-device' tag.

Comment: Do `echo "${ARRAY[$1]}" work?

Comment: Could you please clarify? You _are_ using `$i` as an iterator. When does it not work?

Comment: ${ARRAY[$1]} not working for me.
clarify? When i'm using $i in ${ARRAY[$i]} echo prints blank line. When i'm using number (0, 1, 2, 3...) ${ARRAY[3]} it's working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, how is `$1` relevant? Show the code that does not work and explain what you expected to get and what you actually get.

Comment: Try with the top line as `for ((i=0; i<"${#ARRAY[@]}"; i+=2))`. If this doesn't work, please post more of your script.

Comment: `${array}` is equivalent to `${array[0]}`, not the size of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below script. It should work.

```
declare -a array=('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '10' '11')
for ((i=0; i<=${#array[@]}; i+=2 )) ;
  do
     echo "Current Iterator i value:" $i
     echo "Array element at this position:" ${array[$i]}
 done
```

**Output of the script**

```
Current Iterator i value: 0
Array element at this position: 1
Current Iterator i value: 2
Array element at this position: 3
Current Iterator i value: 4
Array element at this position: 5
Current Iterator i value: 6
Array element at this position: 7
Current Iterator i value: 8
Array element at this position: 9
Current Iterator i value: 10
Array element at this position: 11
```

**Explanation**

I have initially declared an array with 11 elements.

From your question, I believe you are trying to iterate through all the elements available in the array.

`${#array[@]}` - This is used to determine the length of the array.

`${array[$i]}` - This is used to print an element at a particular index.

Comment: I believe you have an extra `#` in `echo ${#array[$i]}`.

Comment: @unxnut, Thanks for letting me know. Fixed the answer :)